# ExtJS collapsible panel not render toolbar on expand?

Tags: extjs, grid, panel, paging, toolbar

I have a trouble about render a grid with toolbar in a collapsible panel. As you see on code at bottom, I have reader, store, grid with bbar and panel. When I set collapsible property of panel to **false** grid's toolbar render perfectly. But, when I set panel collapsible property to **true** then I expand panel, I can not see the toolbar. I want to show grid with toolbar and data on panel expand without any trouble. How can I repair this code?

Thx all.

```
var reader_DailyActivity = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    totalProperty       : 'total',
    successProperty : 'success',
    root            : 'data',
    fields          : [
                        {name: 'date'},
                        {name: 'time'},
                {name: 'description'},
                {name: 'speed'},
                {name: 'distance'},
                {name: 'type'},
                {name: 'source'}
            ]
});

var store_DailyActivity = new Ext.data.Store({
    id      : 'dailyActivityStoreID',
    reader      : reader_DailyActivity
});

var pagingToolbar = new Ext.PagingToolbar({
    pageSize    : 20,
    buttonAlign     : 'center',
    store       : store_DailyActivity
});

var DailyActivityGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    id          : 'dailyActivityGrid',
    store           : store_DailyActivity,
    loadMask        : true,
    height          : 300,
    autoScroll      : true,
    viewConfig      : { 
        emptyText       : 'No Record Found',
        deferEmptyText  : false,
        forceFit        : true
    },
    columns         :[
                    {header: 'Date', dataIndex: 'date'},
                    {header: 'Time', dataIndex: 'time'},
                    {header: 'Description', dataIndex: 'description'},
                    {header: 'Speed', dataIndex: 'speed'},
                    {header: 'Distance', dataIndex: 'distance'},
                    {header: 'Type', dataIndex: 'type'},
                    {header: 'Source', dataIndex: 'source'}
                ],
    bbar        : pagingToolbar
});

var VehicleDetail = new Ext.Panel({
    title       : 'Activity Details',
    id      : 'panel_DetailID',
    collapsible : true,
    collapsed   : true,
renderTo    : 'renderedDivID',
    items       : DailyActivityGrid,
    listeners   : {
        'expand' : function(hede)
        {
            var panelMask = Ext.getCmp('panel_DetailID');
            // mask grid panel
            panelMask.getEl().mask('Please Wait');

        Ext.Ajax.request({                 
                url: 'url comes here',
                params: 
                {
                    param1  : reqParam1,
            start   : 0,
            limit   : 20
                },
                success: function (result, request) 
                {                   
                    var resData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
                    store_DailyActivity.loadData(resData);
                    // unmask grid panel
                    panelMask.getEl().unmask();
                },
                failure: function ()
                {
                    console.log('error');
                }
        });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try to remove the height of the GridPanel. I experienced the same issue in RowExpander Where I was trying to load grid on expander. In my case, Grid displayed fine but tbar & bbar were not displaying due to height constraints. Therefore, I tried to remove the height of the grid and it brought success for me. Your issue looks similar to mine, so please try this suggestion. Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

Couple things you can try:

1. Give the containing panel a layout config `layout: 'fit'`.
2. Use explicit docked items i.e., delete `bbar: pagingToolbar` and put in this:

> ```
> dockedItems: [{
>     xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
>     dock: 'bottom',
>     pageSize: 20,
>     buttonAlign: 'center',
>     store: store_DailyActivity
> }],
> ```

Comment: thx a lot Geronimo, I tried your answer but it couldn't work. I put dockedItems to my grid, after that I expand collapsed panel, it didn't put bar.